# Rolling groupby nunique count based on start and end dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a unique ID, a start date, and an end date. Over the course of a year, the ID can start, stop, and be restarted.

I would like to get a groupby nunique count of IDs over the course of a year.
Currently, I can count unique values for a start date of the ID, but how exactly do I incorporate the end date?

```
fun = pd.DataFrame({'ZIP_KEY': ['A', 'B','C', 'A', 'B', 'A'],
                   'start_month': [1, 2, 2, 6, 8, 10],
                   'end_month': [4, 3, 7, 7, 12, 12]})

fun.groupby('start_month')['ZIP_KEY'].nunique()

start_month
1     1
2     2
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     1
7     0
8     1
9     0
10    1
11    0
12    0
```

Essentially, if an ID starts in January and ends in March, I'd like it to be included in the count for February and March, not just January, which is how my current method is operating.

Desired Output:

```
    start_month
1     1
2     3
3     3
4     2
5     1
6     2
7     2
8     1
9     1
10    2
11    2
12    2
```

Any tips or help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can list all the months between start and end, explode and finally count

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ZIP_KEY': ['A', 'B','C', 'A', 'B', 'A'],
                   'start_month': [1, 2, 2, 6, 8, 10],
                   'end_month': [4, 3, 7, 7, 12, 12]})

df["list"] = df.apply(lambda x: list(range(x["start_month"], x["end_month"]+1)), 
                      axis=1)

df = df.explode("list")

df.groupby("list")["ZIP_KEY"].nunique()
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to re-create the DataFrame where you expand the ranges to all months within the range and replicate the key across every row. Then you can use a normal `groupby`.

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'month': range(st, en+1), 'key': k}) 
                for k, st, en in zip(fun['ZIP_KEY'], fun['start_month'], fun['end_month'])])

df.groupby('month').key.nunique()
#month
#1     1
#2     3
#3     3
#4     2
#5     1
#6     2
#7     2
#8     1
#9     1
#10    2
#11    2
#12    2
#Name: key, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little fun using pd.IntervalIndex with pandas 1.0.0.

```
ii = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(fun['start_month'], fun['end_month'], closed='both')
monthrange = np.arange(1,13)
pd.Series(monthrange, index=monthrange).apply(lambda x: sum(ii.contains(x)))\
  .rename_axis('months').rename('count')
```

Output:

```
months
1     1
2     3
3     3
4     2
5     1
6     2
7     2
8     1
9     1
10    2
11    2
12    2
Name: count, dtype: int64
```